# Use value in table as column name in query result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I have the following table which you can also find in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d989b1/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Flows(
    Flow_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    FlowType TEXT,
    Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Flows
(Flow_Date, Product, FlowType, Quantity)
VALUES 
("2019-05-23", "Product A", "Inbound", "500"),
("2019-10-08", "Product A", "Outbound", "200"),
("2019-11-08", "Product A", "Outbound", "100"),
("2019-11-08", "Product B", "Inbound", "700"),
("2019-11-24", "Product A", "Inbound", "200"),
("2019-12-14", "Product A", "Inbound", "400"),
("2019-12-14", "Product A", "Outbound", "300"),
("2020-12-14", "Product B", "Outbound", "650"),
("2020-02-08", "Product B", "Inbound", "250"),
("2020-02-15", "Product A", "Outbound", "240"),
("2020-02-15", "Product B", "Outbound", "170"),
("2020-02-24", "Product A", "Outbound", "125"),
("2020-02-25", "Product A", "Inbound", "470");
```

And I use the following query to get the quantity of the `Inbounds` and `Outbounds`:

```
SELECT Product, Flowtype, sum(Quantity)
FROM Flows
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

All this works perfectly.

---

Now, I am wondering if it is possible to use `Inbound` and `Outbound` as `column name` in the results of the query. 
 The result should look like this:

```
             Inbound        Outbound
Product A    1570            965
Product B    950             820
```

What do I need to change in my query to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggreagation. This requires you to remove column `FlowType` from the `GROUP BY` clause and use it in conditional expressions within aggregate functions:

```
SELECT 
    Product, 
    sum(case when FlowType = 'Inbound' then Quantity else 0 end) Inbound,
    sum(case when FlowType = 'Outbound' then Quantity else 0 end) Outbound
FROM Flows
GROUP BY Product;
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I need. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d989b1/4

Answer (score 0):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
SELECT Product, 
       sum(case when FlowType = 'Inbound' then Quantity else 0 end),
       sum(case when FlowType = 'Outbound' then Quantity else 0 end)
FROM Flows
GROUP BY Product;
```

Comment: @GMB. . . There is nothing to do copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Product, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN FlowType = 'Inbound' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Inbound,
 SUM(CASE WHEN FlowType = 'Outbound' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Outbound
FROM Flows
GROUP BY Product